# facet_grid label_both wrap the label text dynamic facet variables in shiny plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, text-formatting, facet-grid

so I am struggling to get a plot working like I want.  I have a facet_grid where the variables facetted is determined dynamically in a shiny app...

`facet_grid(facetFormula, labeller = label_both)`

where...

`facetFormula <- as.formula(paste(input$filter2Var, "~", input$filter1Var))`

this works fine, except that i'd rather a linebreak as the variable "name: value" separator instead of the colon.  i've poked around with other arguments (`multi_line`, `sep`), using `label_both()` or `label_wrap_gen()` or `labeller()` instead of `label_both` no parenthesis... and am getting no where, probably stumbling over the already complex issue of dynamic variables to be facetted by.  i've tried treating arguments to these various functions with `!!sym()` or `as.formula()`, but i really don't know what i am doing and probably messing up several things in trying to just add some simple text wrapping to my facet labels.  any help is much appreciated!

UPDATE...

```
cases <- c("case1_has_long_name", "case2_long_too", "case3_long_as_well", "case4_also_long", "case5_long")
the_first_variable <- cases[round(runif(100,1,3))]
variable_number_two <- cases[round(runif(100,1,5))]
var1 <- "the_first_variable"
var2 <- "variable_number_two"
facetFormula <- as.formula(paste(var1, "~", var2))
myX <- runif(100,0,10)
myY <- runif(100,-5,5)
myData <- data.frame(myX, myY, the_first_variable, variable_number_two)
ggplot(myData, aes(x = myX, y = myY)) +
  geom_point(alpha = .5) +
  facet_grid(facetFormula,
             labeller = label_both)
```

this generates a plot with my issue, where the facet labels are too big.  i just want to learn how to make the labels wrap.  was thinking as a simple start, instead of ":" as the separator between variable name and variable value, i could use "\n" as the seperator.  the awkwardness of specifying my facet variables as variable themselves comes from them being dynamically defined in a shiny app.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. It’s easier to help if you make your question reproducible: include a minimal dataset in the form of an object for example if a data frame as df <- data.frame(…) where … is your variables and values or use dput(head(df)). Include the code you have tried and set out your expected answer. These links should be of help: [mre] and [ask]

Comment: thanks Peter, you're absolutely right... i edited my question with some better code and data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrapping the facet labels could be achieved like so:

A labeller takes as its first argument a df with the variable names and labels. In your case a df with one column. The column contains the labels, the column name is the var name.

To wrap the labels I use a wrapper function around `label_both` where I first wrap the labels before passing the manipulated df to label_both. To make the wrapping work I replaced all underscores by spaces.

```r
library(ggplot2)

my_label <- function(x) {
  # Wrap var names
  names(x)[[1]] <- stringr::str_wrap(gsub("_", " ", names(x)[[1]]), 10)
  # Wrap value labels
  x[[1]] <- stringr::str_wrap(gsub("_", " ", x[[1]]), 10)
  # Call label both with sep "\n"
  label_both(x, sep = "\n")
}

ggplot(myData, aes(x = myX, y = myY)) +
  geom_point(alpha = .5) +
  facet_grid(facetFormula, labeller = my_label)
```

[image]

Comment: this is awesome, thank you!  i was really struggling with, if using some function like label_both(), how to define the arguments for it.  the way you've implemented things... ggplot defines the arguments and passes them, and all that confusion for me is avoided.  a lot is going on here and i definitely wasn't on track to figure this out alone, thank you!